# Cannot install JDK in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: java

I tried to install JDK and JRE converting into `.deb` file from `.rpm` using alien.
It goes like this

```
(Reading database ... 209313 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack jdk1.8.0-112_1.8.0112-fcs-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking jdk1.8.0-112 (1.8.0112-fcs-1) over (1.8.0112-fcs-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-112.postrm: line 586: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-112.postrm: line 598: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
dpkg: warning: subprocess old post-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
find: '/usr/java/*': No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm: line 586: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm: line 598: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing archive jdk1.8.0-112_1.8.0112-fcs-1_amd64.deb (--install):
subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 127
find: '/usr/java/*': No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm: line 586: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm: line 598: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
jdk1.8.0-112_1.8.0112-fcs-1_amd64.deb*
```

It goes unpacking and says

```
E: The package jdk1.8.0-112 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it
```

I once stopped the conversion of .rpm to .deb suddenly and tried to install that partially converted .deb file. Is this causes problems.
What to do..?**

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised to see an alien converted package fail to install. I'm actually surprised when they succeed! You may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788345/how-to-install-jdk-on-ubuntu-linux) useful.

Comment: Please don't format your posts like that. All that bold and random punctuation makes it very difficult to read.